# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.ores.async.NeoUtils

Tags: java, maven

I have a library, all the files are in the same package:

```
org.ores.async
```

But I am getting this error:

> ```
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.ores.async.NeoUtils
> ```

At first I thought it might be a circular dependency, but it doesn't look like it, especially since all the classes are in the same package. I keep googling for a hint but I have tried everything and keep getting the same problem.

Anyone know what this might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't flag this. This was my original question. The other answers were for different questions posed by different askers, where this answer is a potential answer.

I had this:

```
 class Util {
  static boolean isNeverAsync = System.getenv().get("asyncc_exclude_redundancy").equals("yes");
}
```

you can probably see the problem, the env var might return null instead of string. So just to test my theory, I changed it to:

```
 class Util {
  static boolean isNeverAsync = false;
}
```

and the problem went away. Too bad that Java can't give you the exact stack trace of the error though, kinda weird.

the way to initialize it safely might be:

```
  static boolean isNeverAsync = false;

  static {
    var env = System.getenv().get("asyncc_exclude_redundancy");
    isNeverAsync = env != null && env.equals("yes");
  }
```